# how to select username from table have multiple userId

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-view

User example:

```
==================
Username   UserId
---------- --------
  A         1
  B         2
===============
```

and another table like this:

```
================================================
sendUserId    insertUserId    printUserId  .....
--------------------------------------------
    1             2              1  
================================================
```

How i can create view to select user info:

```
sendUserName  insertUserName   printUserName
============================================
   A             B                 A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - by joining of multiple instance of user table like below

```
select u1.Username as sendUserName,u2.Username as insertUserName 
,u3.Username as printUserName
from anothertable
inner join user u1 on sendUserId=u1.userid
inner join user u2 on insertUserId=u2.userid
inner join user u3 on printUserId=u3.userid
```

Comment: I'd use LEFT JOIN. (In case there are nullable columns.)